# Issue redirecting after submitting in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to redirect after the form is submitted anything that has not the id `contact-370` to a remote URL. The issue right now is that the contact form is also redirecting and it shouldn't.

```
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function (event) {
    if ('contact-370' !== event.detail.contactFormId) {
        var newTab = window.open('', '_blank');
        newTab.location.href = 'https://mycoolurl.com/';
    }
}, false);
```

https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/

I'm using the latest version of Contact Form 7, so `on_sent_ok` and `on_submit` are deprecated. What am I doing wrong? I'm open to a different solution. Thanks.

Comment: `event.detail.contactFormId` is a number not `contact-xx` it would be `'370'` so in this case, it would never be equal to `contact-370`

Comment: When you look at the source in the browser what you see is id="contact-370". 

Comment: When you console.log `event.detail` you see a number  . It's also specified in the docs. https://contactform7.com/dom-events/

Comment: https://alexisl26.sg-host.com/volunteers/

Answer (score 0):

To integrate safely with stripe.com can be an intricate programming task. I respectfully suggest you use some [tested](https://stripe.com/docs/connectors/non-stripe-connectors) [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/stripe/) unless you have Javascript and HTML skillz, knowledge of how to repel cybercriminals, and some time to develop and test your stuff. CF7 has a [stripe.com addon plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-paypal-add-on/).

Seriously. I know this isn't an answer to your question. But I've been through really detailed audits (to Payment Card Industry Standards) and it saved us an unbelievable amount of auditor trouble when we were able to say "we use stripe.com's APIs for payment". Don't DIY the use of those APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The page you reference is form ID 330 it appears.

Your code should be this then.

```js
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function (event) {
    // the contact form ID is a number as a string.
    if ('330' !== event.detail.contactFormId) {
        var newTab = window.open('', '_blank');
        newTab.location.href = 'https://mycoolurl.com/';
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: In CF7 you can add attributes to the shortcode to give it a more meaningful name like the slug and the name given by default which is a number that means nothing. I tried it like that and didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

**For now**, I just got rid of the `if` and placed the script on **Register** and **Volunteers**, and is working as it should. It's ugly but it works.